# Error a la hora de llamar a un método con Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-swing

Intento llamar a un método de otro método para que me lea un archivo y depuse escriba los resultados en un archivo externo. pero estoy teniendo problema a la hora de llamar al método.

---

==== **Código** =====

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


// Declared class Invie
public class Invie {
    // Declared Object Scanner; 
  static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Declaring the metohd menu
// And declaring menu items.
// Declaring variable lisMenu for creating menu
 public static void Menu () {
    String listMenu = "";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Invie App");

    do {
        listMenu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "a. Add items\n b. Show items\n c. Remove items\n x. Exit", "Menu", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        if (listMenu.equals ("a")) {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Upc Number of product:\n", "Addign items", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name of product:\n", "Addign items", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Date of product:\n", "Addign items", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Quantity Sold of product:\n", "Addign items", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Items Prices of product:\n", "Addign items", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if (listMenu.equals ("b")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Showing items");
        }
        else if (listMenu.equals ("c")) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to delete a product? ", "Delet the items", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
        }
        else if (listMenu.equals ("x")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for user own system. See it soon!", "Exit!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try agen.", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }while(!listMenu.equals("x"));
}   

     // Declaring the metohd call name
    // And declaring multiple variable
    // Reader, fileInput, fileOutput and the array name productNamesList has 50 items
    // Adding integer variable matchesCount, date, upcNumber, experDate, quantitySold, itemsPrices
    // Collect the data when the user enters the product number
    public static void Name (String listMenu) {
        FileReader reader;
        Scanner fileInput;
        PrintWriter fileOutput;
        String productNamesList [] = new String [30],
        product, strLine;

        int matchesCount = 0, date, upcNumber, experDate, quantitySold, itemsPrices;

        String namesOfInputFile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name of the input file and add .txt: ");

        String namesOfOutputFile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name of the output file and add .txt: ");

        // Input try
        try {
            reader = new FileReader(namesOfInputFile);
            fileInput = new Scanner (reader);

            while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
                strLine = fileInput.nextLine();
                product = strLine;
                upcNumber = Integer.valueOf(strLine);

                if (productNamesList.equals("b")) {
                    productNamesList[matchesCount] = product;
                    matchesCount += 1;
                } 
            }
            fileInput.close();
        }catch(IOException error) {
            System.out.print("File error " + error);
        }

        // Output try
        try {
            fileOutput = new PrintWriter(namesOfOutputFile);
            for (int i = matchesCount - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
                if (namesOfOutputFile.equals(productNamesList)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, productNamesList[i]);
                }
            }
            fileOutput.close();
        }catch(IOException error) {
            System.out.print("File error " + error);
        }
    }
    // The main function
    // Calling the matohd
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Invie myMenu = new Invie();
        String[] menuList = {"Meet", "Fish", "Cake"};
        Menu();
        Name(listMenu);
  }
}
```

---

El Error es el siguiente:

====**Error**=====

> PS C:\Users\herna\Documents\Projecto-Final> javac Invie.java
>   Invie.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
>                   Name(listMenu);
>                        ^   symbol:   variable listMenu   location: class Invie 1 error

Comment: Dentro del alcance del metodo `main` la variable `listMenu` no existe, Ni si quiera de forma global.

Comment: Fijate que dentro del metodo `Menu` si estas creando la variable `listMenu`, pero dentro del `main` no existe.

Comment: vale entiendo no me avía fijado en eso, lo que necesito es crear la variable listMenu para que el que main lo reconozca ?

Comment: Exacto, pero tambien echale un ojo al metodo `Name` el cual espera como parametro un `String listMenu` pero dentro del metodo nunca lo utilizas.

Comment: En el `main` tambien declaras `String[] menuList` y nunca lo usas, dentro del metodo `Menu` tienes a `listMenu` el cual no se si necesitas retornarlo.

Comment: *Creo que deberias analizar el contexto de lo que quieres hacer con el codigo que tienes*, Para resolver tu problema de compilacion puedes declarar la variable `listMenu` dentro del `main` **ó** borrar el parametro `String listMenu` del metodo `Name`.

Comment: vale entiendo, gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error:

```
Invie.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
                Name(listMenu);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable listMenu
```

se refiere a que no encuentra la definición de la variable `listMenu`.

---

La definición de la variable `listMenu` se esta realizando dentro de el método:

```
 public static void Menu () {
    String listMenu = "";
   ...
   ...
 }
```

por lo tanto al usarla dentro del método `main()` no encuentra su definición, debes realizarla a nivel de clase (global):

```
public class Invie {

  static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String listMenu = "";

 public static void Menu () {
 ...
 ...
 }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias pro tu ayuda ahora lo tengo mucho mas claro.

Answer (score 0):

Hola la solución es dejar tu variable `String listMenu = "";`
Como global a la clase y estatica:

```
public class Invie {
// Declared Object Scanner;
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static String listMenu = "";
```

Esto porque la variable listMenu esta en otro contexto, es una varible local así como la tienes.

Saludos y esper que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mario, de seguro me va ha servir.